# JPQL cannot join tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpql

Can you help me to join these tables people. My JPQL query is not working

```
@Query("Select bp, p from Perks as p, BokPerks as bp where bp.bookingID =:bookingID and bp.payment_id = p.id")
    List<Payment> getTEST(@Param("bookingId")long bookingID);
```

Can't solve it for an hour already, maybe its a simple mistake but I already blocked a bit :)
Table for BokPerks entity:

```
'131', NULL, '2'
'131', NULL, '3'
'132', NULL, '1'
'132', NULL, '2'
'132', NULL, '3'
'15', '1', '4'
'33', '2', '1'
'33', '2', '2'
'33', '2', '3'
'38', '3', '4'
```

perks table:

```
'1', 'lorem ipsum'
'2', '1234'
'3', 'hello '
'4', 'examples'
```

Comment: Please define "not working": Do you get an Sql Error, a Java Exception or just not the result you expect? Also: What is `tbp` in your query? You did not define an alias with that name.

Comment: its cannot create bean exception as these are hardcoded queries in the repository @Query

Comment: Do you have the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: And can you please post the `Error stack` you got?

Comment: emmm maybe that the breaker: @AssociationOverrides({@AssociationOverride(name = "pk.tripBooking", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "trip_booking_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.TripPayment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "trip_payment_id"))})

Comment: that entity is ***t :D

Comment: there will be something specific with that kind of entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doe not have JOIN. Should be something like this

```
@Query("Select bp, p from Perks as p INNER JOIN p.BokPerks as bp where tbp.bookingID =:bookingID and tbp.payment_id = p.id")
```

I wrote `INNER JOIN p.BokPerks` but actually there should be name of property referenced. Can't tell exact syntax without your entities classes

Suppose `BokPerks` has `perk` reference property. Then the query should be

```
from  BokPerks as bp INNER JOIN bp.perk as p
```

Comment: p have only id and description, no reference to other objects

Comment: Then BokPerks must have a reference to Perks.

Comment: btw you can join tables in jpql only with the where clause as well as in sql too

Answer (score 1):

Well you can simply see that you are using an unkown `tbp` alias in your query:

```
@Query("Select bp, p from Perks as p, BokPerks as bp where tbp.bookingID =:bookingID and tbp.payment_id = p.id")
```

You wrote `Select bp, p from Perks as p` and then you wrote `where tbp.bookingID =:bookingID and tbp.payment_id = p.id`

Change it to:

```
@Query("Select bp, p from Perks as p, BokPerks as bp where bp.bookingID =:bookingID and bp.payment_id = p.id")
```